# Retrofit post request change to form-data

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2.+ latest version to make the post api call, webservice only supports the form-data but api call I make from retrofit takes x-www-form-urlencoded content deposition type.

I believe it's because of the annotation @FormUrlEncoded how to make calls that support form-data body type.

here is the code I am using.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login/{guestToken}")
    Call<UserLogin> loginUser(@Path("guestToken") String guestToken, @Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

here is my api call

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
                Call<UserLogin> call = apiService.loginUser(prefs.getToken(),"dinesh","123456789");
                call.enqueue(new Callback<UserLogin>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UserLogin> call, Response<UserLogin> response) {
                        if(TextUtils.equals(response.body().getResponseCode(),"2010")){
                           code = response.body().data.getVerificationCode();
                            Log.d("Verify Code", code);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(SigninActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.reached_limit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UserLogin> call, Throwable t) {
                        // Log error here since request failed
                        Log.e("response", t.toString());
                    }
                });
```

I tried specifying the Content-disposition using @Header annotation too in the retrofit interface.

Comment: what's your question

Comment: I need to change the content deposition type to "form-data" and post the params but it's not happening probably because we use tag @FormUrlEncoded for the post request

Comment: by using @FormUrlEncoded u r getting success or not ?